# XAML collection initialization from WPF custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer, windows-forms-designer

How do I generate some XAML collection items entries just after dropping my WPF custom control on the WPF window surface?

Now, each time I drop it on the window, I need to add items manually typing XAML even if I know in advance I will need at least five of them.

In practice I need to generate additional XAML on my WPF custom control initialization.

Thanks.

Comment: Unsure what you mean, especially with "XAML collection items entries". Code please. Often you'd just bind data in the code behind.

Comment: @Peter: I just want to drag & drop a custom control representing a map Legend and would like to get it (just after dropping it on the WPF window) with some colors already in the collection. Afterward, from XAML I will add or remove some of them but I don't like to get the empty list at first.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `DesignData`. This allows you to specify design-time data that can be populated in your custom control during the Design Process.

The basic workflow is to create a XAML data context file and add  it to your project with the Build Type of DesignData and then to apply the d:DesignData property in the `DataTemplate` of your custom control.

Good examples of how this works can be found [here](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-use-designdata-to-populate-controls-with-design-time-data-in-silverlight-and-wpf/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx).

Comment: Will check and let you know. We normally prefer to use code instead of templates...